# Replace variable of a function while calling it in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, variables, methods

Sorry for my bad english.

Is there any way to replace variable of a method from outside?

Suppose i have two files app.py and try.py.

In app -

```
def call():
  c=5
  return c
```

In try -

```
from app import *
c=1000
d=call()
print(d)
```

When i run try, here i want the output to be 1000 not 6. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Remove the `c=5` from `app`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to change the value as opposed to rewrite the function to pass `c` as a parameter.

Comment: Right, then `c` becomes a global variable.  However, overuse of global variables is generally not good programming practice, because it can cause functions to change behavior unexpectedly.  Code like this means it is time to think about creating a class, so that the object can contain its own state.

Comment: `def  call(what_to_return): return what_to_return` - `call(1000)` - but what you want to do makes no real sense - why would you return exactly what you pass in - why pass in at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to change `c` dynamically. Python compiles `c = 5` into a LOAD_CONST op code as seen in the disassembly. And changing that op code would require, um, .... I don't know.

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> def call():
...   c=5
...   return c
... 
>>> dis(call)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (c)

  3           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (c)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can monkey patch, though. Write your own implemenation of `call` and assign it dynamically at the start of your program.

```
import app

# from app, a reimplementation of call
def my_app_call_impl(c=1000):
    return c

app.call = my_app_call_impl
```

Answer (score 0):

add c argument to the function and use it like that

app file

```
def call(c):
    return c
```

The second file

```
from app import *
c = 1000
d = call(c)
print(d)
```

if you want to c have a default value then app file should look like this

```
def call(c = 5):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define parameters for the call function:

app.py:

```py
def call(c): # one parameter, c
    return c
```

try.py

```py
from app import *
c = 1000
d = call(c) # function called with c as an argument

print(d) # 1000
```

You can also use 5 as a default:

app.py

```py
def call(c = 5):
    return c
```

try.py

```py
from app import *

d = call()
print(d) # 5
```

[Functions in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function-argument)

Answer (score 0):

*in app.py : *

```
def call(c=5):
    return c
```

*in try.py : *

```
from app import *
d=call(1000)
print(d)
```